# "Black Hats" in "The Number of the Beast"

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, the-number-of-the-beast

Some years ago, I ran into a statement that the identity of the villains that start chasing the party in Heinlein's *Number of the Beast* could be figured out from internal clues.  I completely failed.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are all Heinlein himself. The clues are that all of them have names that are anagrams of his name. They represent the author entering the story to move it along. I'm not sure I would go so far as to say the book is a guide on how to write. But it certain was Heinlein being playful with the concept of the book.

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_%28novel%29) article goes into some detail about this.

Comment: Just on a related note -- he does this a number of times; in this book, the author is acting as the villain (EVERY villain, in fact), but he mentions in other books how the author HAS to be the villain for most stories; he's the one making the hero suffer. See the end of The Cat Who Walks thru Walls for an example, or Jubal Harshaw's comments on it at the end of Numer of the Beast. It's a real issue for authors, who sometimes get depressed by developing a character they like, then having to abuse him/her over and over to generate a story.